# Unable to recover inconsistency in Hbase

Tags: hadoop, hbase

1. I used **hbase hbck** and got such error:

ERROR: Region { meta => t1002,036,1707080843568.3b36c407cad3bcd56ab04a8c7f30a749., hdfs => hdfs://hacluster/hbase/data/default/t1002/3b36c407cad3bcd56ab04a8c7f30a749, deployed => , replicaId => 0 } not deployed on any region server.
ERROR: There is a hole in the region chain between 036 and 042.  You need to create a new .regioninfo and region dir in hdfs to plug the hole.
ERROR: Found inconsistency in table t1002

2. Then I tried to fix it with
   **hbase hbck -fixAssignments t1002**
   But it is still inconsistent:

2024-02-14 16:13:46,418 INFO  [hbasefsck-pool1-t36] util.HBaseFsckRepair: Region still in transition, waiting for it to become assigned: {ENCODED => 3b36c407cad3bcd56ab04a8c7f30a749, NAME => 't1002,036,1707080843568.3b36c407cad3bcd56ab04a8c7f30a749.', STARTKEY => '036', ENDKEY => '042'}
2024-02-14 16:13:47,525 INFO  [hbasefsck-pool1-t36] util.HBaseFsckRepair: Region still in transition, waiting for it to become assigned: {ENCODED => 3b36c407cad3bcd56ab04a8c7f30a749, NAME => 't1002,036,1707080843568.3b36c407cad3bcd56ab04a8c7f30a749.', STARTKEY => '036', ENDKEY => '042'}

2024-02-14 16:14:47,450 WARN  [hbasefsck-pool1-t36] util.HBaseFsck: Unable to complete check or repair the region 't1002,036,1707080843568.3b36c407cad3bcd56ab04a8c7f30a749.'.
java.io.IOException: Region {ENCODED => 3b36c407cad3bcd56ab04a8c7f30a749, NAME => 't1002,036,1707080843568.3b36c407cad3bcd56ab04a8c7f30a749.', STARTKEY => '036', ENDKEY => '042'} failed to move out of transition within timeout 120000ms
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.HBaseFsckRepair.waitUntilAssigned(HBaseFsckRepair.java:149)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.HBaseFsck.tryAssignmentRepair(HBaseFsck.java:2223)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.HBaseFsck.checkRegionConsistency(HBaseFsck.java:2435)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.HBaseFsck.access$1200(HBaseFsck.java:203)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.HBaseFsck$CheckRegionConsistencyWorkItem.call(HBaseFsck.java:1994)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.HBaseFsck$CheckRegionConsistencyWorkItem.call(HBaseFsck.java:1982)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2024-02-14 16:14:47,454 WARN  [hbasefsck-pool1-t36] util.HBaseFsck: Skip region 't1002,036,1707080843568.3b36c407cad3bcd56ab04a8c7f30a749.'
2024-02-14 16:14:47,493 INFO  [main] client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Closing master protocol: MasterService
2024-02-14 16:14:47,493 INFO  [main] client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Closing zookeeper sessionid=0xeb0113b8423ca6f3
2024-02-14 16:14:47,500 INFO  [main-EventThread] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: EventThread shut down for session: 0xeb0113b8423ca6f3
2024-02-14 16:14:47,500 INFO  [main] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Session: 0xeb0113b8423ca6f3 closed
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: 1 region(s) could not be checked or repaired.  See logs for detail.
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.HBaseFsck.checkAndFixConsistency(HBaseFsck.java:1948)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.HBaseFsck.onlineConsistencyRepair(HBaseFsck.java:697)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.HBaseFsck.onlineHbck(HBaseFsck.java:731)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.HBaseFsck.exec(HBaseFsck.java:5198)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.HBaseFsck$HBaseFsckTool.run(HBaseFsck.java:4961)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:76)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:90)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.HBaseFsck.main(HBaseFsck.java:4949)
2024-02-14 16:14:48,097 INFO  [Thread-10] util.HBaseFsck: Finishing hbck

How to resolve this problem, what need to do further?